# How to code a button in HTML to open a html page in Notepad

Tags: html

Hello I have a server inventory with me. But we wanted to make it easy by including a button which upon clicking should open our main html page in notepad so that anyone without a coding knowledge can open it and add a new server or make any changes easily. Is it possible? I have tried many things but failed. help is very much appreciated. To put it in a simple way, I want to create a button in my html page which should open my html page in notepad but not in browser.

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function runProgram()
        {
            var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");                 
            var notepad = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" /e /s /u /wl /wr /maximize";
            var file = "file:\\\10.35.114.123\e$\Inventory\Somos\Home1.html";
            shell.Run(notepad+file);
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="javascript:runProgram()">Run program</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless you create an app that reacts on certain protocol types i would say no

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some examples?

Comment: @putvande - I have added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first reaction was say that it's not possible, but since in your code you use a local intranet address you could achieve that with this conditions:

- You have to use Internet Explorer, since `ActiveXObject` is supported only by IE, being that object a proprietary MS extension.
- You are OK with lowering a bit the security settings of the local intranet zone (only that zone, Internet security settings remain unchanged).  If you don't do that you the script will fail with the message *"Automation server can't create object"*.
- Your users have file network access to that location: that directory is a shared folder and users have the appropriate permissions to access it (i.e. they can access it using Windows Explorer).

First, you have to modify your code, since the parameters you use are not valid for Windows Notepad, also you have to remove the *"file://"* protocol and use double slashes in the network path (because the `Shell` object expect strings in C/C++ format):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function runProgram()
    {
        // only works in Internet Explorer
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");                 
        //var notepad = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"; // full path optional for notepad
        var notepad = "notepad.exe"; // use full path for programs outside Windows folder
        var file = "\\\\10.35.114.123\\e$\\Inventory\\Somos\\Home1.html";
        shell.Run(notepad+" "+file);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="runProgram()">Open Notepad</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you have to modify the settings of Internet Explorer in each computer:

- Open `Internet options`, and in the `Security` tab select `Local Intranet`. **Important:** make sure that you change settings *only* for the local intranet.
- Press the `Custom level...` button and find the `Initialize scripts and ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting` option, then select `Prompt` or `Enable` (better the first one).
- Open the page in Internet Explorer, it a message appears at the bottom saying that Intranet settings are off by default then press `Turn on Intranet settings`.

After this, pressing the "Open notepad" button will open Notepad with that file (maybe with a warning).

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin!!